# How to use alias parameter as resource key

Tags: wpf, xaml, ammy

I want to create an alias that creates static resources to be used in my app.

The problem is when I use an alias parameter as the value for the resource's `Key` I get an error.

Is there another way to do this?

```
alias ColorMap(name, color) {
    SolidColorBrush Key=$name { Color: $color }
}

ResourceDictionary {
  @ColorMap("color-bkg", $grey75)
}
```

The XAML that I'm looking for would look like this:

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="color-bkg" Color="#AFB5BF"/>
```

Comment: Key name must match, otherwise there's no need for a Key. What specifically you are trying ?

Comment: Using parameter as a Key value is not implemented yet. I'll try to fix that as soon as possible and will report here.

Comment: This is now possible, just update Ammy from MyGet source. Instructions are here http://www.ammyui.com/documentation/prerelease-builds/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good catch!

This will be possible in a next version (any version after Ammy 1.2.41)

Comment: Thanks @ionoy. I'll get setup with the daily builds. Ammy looks fantastic!